# Having problems with my Guess the number game python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working out with my python 3 and I made a simple project which is a game "Guess the number", I'm having problems here that i could't understand. The game was find until i'm adding something in the script which is to check if `guess = input()` is a number. And i messed up, when i run it, it always keep sending me error messages.
Can you guys check my code and if can how to check if `guess = input()` is a number.

Zelandini

```
import random


def main():
    USER = input('Hello there wht is your name?')
    print('Hello, ' + USER + '')
    question = input('Do you want to play a game? [Yes/No]')

    if question == 'n' or question == 'No' or question == 'no' or question == 'N' or question == 'NO':
        print('Bye, ' + USER + '!')

    if question == 'y' or question == 'Yes' or question == 'Y' or question == 'yes':
        print("Okay, the game is to guess my number,")

        replay()


def replay():
    tries = 1
    number = random.randint(1, 10)

    play_again = True

    print("I'm thinking a number between 1 and 10")
    Guess = input("Have a guess?")

    while play_again:

        if Guess > number:
            print("Go lower, your number is too big")

        if Guess < number:
            print("Go higher, you number is to small")

    while Guess != number:
        tries += 1
        Guess = int(input("Try again?"))

        if tries == 4:
            print('You have out of tries')

            print("\nWould you like to play again?")

            response = input("> ").lower()
            if response not in ("yes", "y"):
                play_again = False
                print("Bye!")

            replay()

        if Guess > number:
            print("Go lower, your number is too big")

        if Guess < number:
            print("Go higher, you number is to small")

    if Guess == number:
        print("Congratulations! You've got it")
        print("\nWould you like to play again?")

    response = input("> ").lower()
    if response not in ("yes", "y"):
        play_again = False
        print("Bye you Sad!")

    replay()
if __name__ == "__replay__":
    replay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. If you want to see if it is a valid `int`, simply cast it to an `int` and catch the `ValueError` exception. If no error is raised, it's a valid integer.

Comment: Here's an example: https://repl.it/repls/AshamedGrimyDiplodocus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this slightly adjusted code (**INDENTATIONS & SCOPES**) you will no longer receive non-stop error messages and can focus on getting the functionality right. I won't spoil that for you, happy debugging. :)

```
import random

def main(): 
USER = input('Hello there wht is your name?')
print('Hello, ' + USER + '')
question = input('Do you want to play a game? [Yes/No]')

if question == 'n' or question == 'No' or question == 'no' or question == 'N' or question == 'NO':
    print('Bye, ' + USER + '!')


if question == 'y' or question == 'Yes' or question == 'Y' or question == 'yes':
    print("Okay, the game is to guess my number,")

replay()

def replay():
tries = 1
number = random.randint(1, 10)

play_again = True

while play_again:

print("I'm thinking a number between 1 and 10")
guess = input("Have a guess?")

while guess != number:
    tries += 1
    guess = int(input("Try again?"))

    if tries == 4:
        print('You have out of tries')

        print("\nWould you like to play again?")

        response = input("> ").lower()
        if response not in ("yes", "y"):
            play_again = False
            print("Bye!")

        replay()

    if guess > number:
        print("Go lower, your number is too big")

    if guess < number:
        print("Go higher, you number is to small")

if guess == number:
print("Congratulations! You've got it")
print("\nWould you like to play again?")

response = input("> ").lower()
if response not in ("yes", "y"):
    play_again = False
    print("Bye you Sad!")

replay()

if name == "main": main()
```

Comment: Can you also add a code to check if user input is a number?